# matplotlib graph disappears in scroll on retina display

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5, retina-display

I'm using PyQt5 (5.13.1) in python 3.7.4

I'm using macos for now (10.14.5) on an imac with one retina display and one non-retina display

I'm plotting a graph using matplotlib inside a scroll area

I've encountered a strange issue. I do not know if posting any code would be useful, but if you think some specific code will help, please let me know what code and i'll post.

here is the weird issue:

On the non-retina monitor, everything works fine. I can scroll up and down and see my graph and other scroll content. When I save the scroll area widget to an image, it is nice. All content is there. But, of course the resolution isn't great because it's the non-retina display.

On the retina monitor, as I scroll down, the bottom of the graph starts to disappear. and more disappears the more I scroll. The saved image looks exactly the same: whatever has disappeared on the screen is actually missing in the image (even though saving the whole scroll area should not do that, and in fact this error does not happen on the non-retina monitor or for content on the retina monitor that is not the matplolib graph. So, just to be clear, the issue is that matplotlib graphs seem to disappear at they are scrolled on my retina monitor.

As you can see from the images, the part of the graph that disappears starts at the bottom, not the part that is no longer visible because of scrolling.

scroll window on non-retina display. no problems

[image]

after dragging window to retina display, the bottom of the figure (from the x-axis) begins to disappear

[image]

So, does anyone know about this matplotlib issue? is there a setting that I seed to implement?

Comment: try with: `app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: EDIT: After adding the code above, it seems saving the scroll area or any widget individually works. So THANK YOU. But, the problem viewing on the screen still exists. I can live with that as long as the graphs come out ok when saving/printing. I'll mark as solved if nothing else comes along.